# How to create right click Menu in NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I am new to this technology , I want to display different *Context Menu* on `Right click` of *Parent Node* and *Child Node*..

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `NSOutlineView` and implement `- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent`.

```
-(NSMenu*)menuForEvent:(NSEvent*)evt 
{
    NSLog(@"menuForEvent %@ %@",self, [self delegate]);
    NSPoint pt = [self convertPoint:[evt locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
    int row=[self rowAtPoint:pt];
    // create menu ...
    return menu;
}
```

On Mac OS 10.5 and above, create NSMenu in nib and set delegate and implement:

```
-(void)menuNeedsUpdate:(NSMenu *)menu
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift Version:

```
class SubclassOutlineView: NSOutlineView {

    override func menu(for event: NSEvent) -> NSMenu? {
        let point = convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
        let row = self.row(at: point)
        let item = self.item(atRow: row)

        let menu = NSMenu()
        // ...

        return menu
    }

}
```

The bit I was missing was `item(atRow:`, which gives you the needed data source item. Found that at this related question:

[How do you add context senstive menu to NSOutlineView (ie right click menu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309602/how-do-you-add-context-senstive-menu-to-nsoutlineview-ie-right-click-menu)